# Android OpenGL ES Color Byte Order

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, endianness

I'm having the problem that my textures are rendering incorrect colors and based on [this](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/color.htm) it seems like Android's reading the colors in reverse order.

I tried solving the problem as the reference says but GL_BGR_EXT is not defined in the Android NDK nor is GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5_REV. How can I reverse the color byte order in the Android NDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it, swapping the R and B channels of your texture. OpenGL supported that feature, but it was removed in OpenGL ES to make drivers more simple.

Comment: I added some operations to swap the R & B  color bytes and it's working now. Thanks

Comment: What exactly was your fix?